# Python xpath engine is not able to parse 2 condition on same tag

Tags: python-3.x

assume I have something like that

```
   <src name="BdsBoot.c">
        <fn name="XXXXX" >
           <probe>test1</probe> 
           <probe>test2</probe> 
        </fn>
   </src>
```

xpath="/src/fn[probe='test1'][probe='test2']" doesn't work even it is valid xpath

Comment: What is the code that you use to load the XML file and apply the XPath?

Comment: tree = ElementTree.parse(file_path)
root = cls.branding_config_tree.getroot()
entry_list = root.findall(xpath_string)